# A more efficient way to take samples from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a piece of code like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'col1': [17,2,3,4,5,5,10,22,31,11,65,86],
    'col2': [6,7,8,9,10,31,46,12,20,37,91,32],
    'col3': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

sampling_period = 3
abnormal_data = set()
for i in range(sampling_period):
    # get index of [0, 3, 6, 9, ...], [1, 4, 7, 10, ...], and [2, 5, 8, 11, ...]
    df_sampled = df[i::sampling_period]
    diff = df_sampled - df_sampled.shift(1)
    # diff >= 5 are considered as an abnormal columns
    abnormal_df = df_sampled[
        diff >= 5
    ].dropna(how="all", axis=1)
    abnormal_data = abnormal_data.union(set(abnormal_df.columns))

print(f"abnormal_data: {abnormal_data}")
```

What the code above does are as the followings:

1. Sampling all the columns in `df` based on `sampling_period`.
2. If the difference between 2 consecutive elements in `df_sampled` is larger than or equal to 5, mark this column as abnormal.
3. Return abnormal columns.

Is there anyway to avoid the *for loop* in the code?

The code above takes a lot of time to run when `sampling_period` and `df` becomes large. I wish that it could run faster.

For example, when my `sampling_period` is 60, and `df.shape` is `(20040, 3562)`, it takes about 683 seconds to run the above code.

Comment: "when sampling_period and df becomes large" - how large is large? And what is "a lot of time"? Sometimes, this is simply unavoidable, and not everything can be magically sped up. Please provide an indication of the size of the actually used dataframe and of the (estimated) time that may take.

Comment: You should also profile the code, perhaps by simply commenting out statements, to see which parts take a long time. My gut feeling is that `abnormal_data = abnormal_data.union(set(abnormal_df.columns))` can take quite some time, especially when `abnormal_data` becomes large.

Comment: I created a somewhat random dataframe of shape (20040, 3562), and ran that with a sampling period of 60. That took about 8 seconds (M1 macbook). What are (roughly) your machine specifications? (Note that in my case, with the random input, all columns contain abnormal data, so I have 3562 column names in the output.)